# Google Apps Script OAuth2 Library Error for Service Accounts if private Key is not stored in apps script file directly

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I successfully set up connection from google apps script to Google Cloud firestore database with a service account. It is working fine as long I store the credentials in the apps script file itself. If I store the private Key of the credential somewhere else (in database, in a drive file, google doc...) oauth2 authentication fails with error: "Invalid Argument: Key" thrown by GAS Oauth2 library.

I investigated further and it seems an encoding/charset problem. If I compare the length of the private Key string between hard coded and stored in a File/DB the length of the key is not equal, but the key-strings seems to be identical.

Some help would be appreciated.

```
function createOAuth() {

// credentials of service account hard coded 
var jsonObj = {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "id of project",
 "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----.....----END PRIVATE KEY-\n",
      "client_email": "servic accoutn email",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",    
    }  

// not working if store attribute private_key somewhere else like:
/*var fileContent = DriveApp.getFileById('idOfFile').getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-8"); //OR
DocumentApp.getBody().getText() //OR
var privateKey = Utilities.newBlob(privatKeyFromCredents).getDataAsString()
//store key in cloud firestore database also not working. 
*/

return OAuth2.createService("Service Account")
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  .setPrivateKey(jsonObj.private_key)
  .setIssuer(jsonObj.client_email)
   .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setCache(CacheService.getScriptCache())
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
  .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore');

var access = service.hasAccess(); // true if jsonObj is hard coded 
// false if stored somewhere else --> error: Invalid Argument: Key
Logger.log('Access: ' + access); 

}
```

Comment: How about storing it in a text file or a bin file?

Comment: About the commented script, if the file of ``idOfFile`` is a text file and the file content of ``idOfFile`` is ``-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----.....----END PRIVATE KEY-\n``, for example, how about ``var privateKey = DriveApp.getFileById('idOfFile').getBlob().getDataAsString();``? By the way, what is ``privatKeyFromCredents`` in your script?

Comment: I tried it also to store the key in a text files (in various formats). but that also did not worked.
the following code was another try to convert the key that was stored in a txt file on drive, creat than a blob and transform the key to another charset: 
var privateKey = Utilities.newBlob(privatKeyFromCredents).getDataAsString()
but that also failed...

Comment: I am wonderin in what format is a hard coded string is stored in an apps script file? because the length of the key string is different if check the length of the variable where the hard coded key is stored compared to read the key in utf-8 form a google doc or text file...

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for replying. At first, I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. As a next method, for example, how about directly upload the downloaded file when the service account is created to Google Drive, and use it? The file is json file. So the private key can be retrieved. Can I ask you about this?

Comment: He Tanaike, thanks for your reply. Indeed now it is working! The trick seems to be, to store the information in json format like the original credentials. Than it is possible to read the file form drive with the following code: 
var fileContent = DriveApp.getFileById('fileID').getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-8");
var serviceCredentials = JSON.parse(fileContent);

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you post the worked script as an answer and accept it, it might be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// get Credentials form Drive in JSON format
var fileContent = DriveApp.getFileById('18t9NnzwKMlmQAnRUa_KovWdDvhk60oZT').getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-8");

var serviceCredentials = JSON.parse(fileContent);
serviceCredentials['service_name'] = "Service Account Name";
serviceCredentials['scope'] = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore ";

var service = OAuth2.createService(serviceCredentials.service_name)
.setTokenUrl(serviceCredentials.token_uri)
.setPrivateKey(serviceCredentials.private_key)
.setIssuer(serviceCredentials.client_email)
.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
.setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
.setParam('access_type', 'offline')
.setScope(serviceCredentials.scope);

// for testing if access oauth setup is working or not
var access = service.hasAccess();
Logger.log('Access: ' + access); //true or false
```

Comment: Code only answers are not exactly great. You should provide some explanatory text that summarizes why your answer works.